# fontweight property has no effect on AnchoredText object?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw some text through an [AnchoredText](https://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredText) (see the code below) but the `fontweight` property does not seem to have any effect:

[image]

I'm using Python 3.7.3 and `matplotlib` 3.1.0.

What am I missing here?

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText


ax = plt.subplot(131)
plt.plot([])
anchored_text = AnchoredText(
    "aaa bb ccc", loc=8,
    prop={'family': 'Ubuntu Condensed', 'size': 35, 'fontweight': 'normal'},
    frameon=False)
ax.add_artist(anchored_text)

ax = plt.subplot(132)
plt.plot([])
anchored_text = AnchoredText(
    "aaa bb ccc", loc=8,
    prop={'family': 'Ubuntu Condensed', 'size': 35, 'fontweight': 'bold'},
    frameon=False)
ax.add_artist(anchored_text)

ax = plt.subplot(133)
plt.plot([])
anchored_text = AnchoredText(
    "aaa bb ccc", loc=8,
    prop={'family': 'Ubuntu Condensed', 'size': 35, 'fontweight': 'light'},
    frameon=False)
ax.add_artist(anchored_text)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you verified that "Ubuntu Condensed" actually has a light fontweight available? In any case, the fontweight argument itself is working fine.

Comment: according to a quick search (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu+Condensed) there's only 'Regular' so it fits your explanation IOBE

Comment: But Kolourpaint allows me to set the bold option on this font. Is that a different thing?

Comment: It's geometrically pretty easy to make any font bolder. Many graphics programs do that if no bold fontset is available. But matplotlib does not have such algorithm in it.

Comment: Than that must be it. Would either of you like to make a quick answer out of these comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu+Condensed there's only 'Regular' style for your choice of font, so using different fontweight parameters will not have any impact